# Runtime TypeCasting in C#

Tags: c#, .net, polymorphism

IDE: VS2010, C# .NET 4.0

I am wondering is there any way to typecast the object in the way variable passed in it for eg:

```
#CODE BLOCK 1  
    private void ReArrangeShapeLocation(Shape currentControl, double scalePrecentageHeight, double scalePrecentageWidth)
    {
        //here I need to type cast control according to their type

        //example code
        int cX = (currentControl as RectangleShape).Location.X;
        int cXo = (currentControl as OvalShape).Location.X;  
        //Computation code.
    }
```

Here Shape  class is available in c# namespace

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks
```

and RectangleShape and OvalShape are child classes of Shape class.

So in above code if I pass

```
ReArrangeShapeLocation(somRectrangleShape1,14,34);
ReArrangeShapeLocation(somOvelShape1,15,15);
```

As here i am passing rectangle and oval shape in same function to get their location in  the function (see code block #1), I need to type cast the Shape object accordingly.

Is there any way in c# to typecast the shape object according to child class whatever I pass in ReArrangeShapeLocation function.

```
#CODE BLOCK 1  
    private void ReArrangeShapeLocationDYNAMIC(Shape currentControl, double scalePrecentageHeight, double scalePrecentageWidth)
    {
        //here I need to type cast control according to their type

        //example code
        int cX = (currentControl as Typeof(currentControl)).Location.X;

    }
```

I know it can be done using switch case which I don't want. Also I know in c# this might be done using Reflaction, But I don't know.

Comment: is there any specific reason you want to typecast as currentControl will have the Location

Comment: If "Location" is not part of any base class and you are sure that currentControl always has a "Location" member and that member always has an int "X" member, you could use dynamic invocation: int cX = ((dynamic)currentControl).Location.X;

Comment: Your last example doesn't really make sense: An object is always of its own type. You need to distinguish between the object as it lives in memory and the variable that references it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually not necessary and exactly the point of polymorphism. Any class derived from `Shape` will have the respective properties declared in `Shape`. So to get the coordinates (which I assume are part of the `Shape` class) it doesn't matter what kind of shape is being passed to the method.

You *can* cast the base object to the specialized object, but only if you are sure that the object you get has the correct type.

For example this works:

```
Shape r = new RectangleShape();
RectangleShape r1 = r as RectangleShape();
```

While this doesn't:

```
Shape p = new PolygonShape();
RectangleShape p1 = p as RectangleShape();
```

---

I noticed that the `Shape` class does not define coordinates, but the [`SimpleShape`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.simpleshape.aspx) class does, which is derived from `Shape`. As you rely on the `Location` property in your code, you need to make sure the `Shape` you get is a `SimpleShape`.

You can change your method declaration to taking a [`SimpleShape`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.simpleshape.aspx) parameter:

```
private void ReArrangeShapeLocation(SimpleShape currentControl, double scalePrecentageHeight, double scalePrecentageWidth)
{
    int cX = currentControl.Location.X;
}
```

Or you can leave it as is and throw an exception if something wrong is passed:

```
private void ReArrangeShapeLocation(Shape currentControl, double scalePrecentageHeight, double scalePrecentageWidth)
{
    if (!(currentControl is SimpleShape))
        throw new ArgumentException("currentControl is not a SimpleShape");

    int cX = (currentControl as SimpleShape).Location.X;
}
```

Or you could extend your method to handling [`LineShape`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.lineshape.aspx) as well:

```
private void ReArrangeShapeLocation(Shape currentControl, double scalePrecentageHeight, double scalePrecentageWidth)
{
    int cX = 0;

    if (currentControl is SimpleShape)
    {
        cX = (currentControl as SimpleShape).Location.X;
    }
    else if (currentControl is LineShape)
    {
        cX = (currentControl as LineShape).X1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer solved my problem thanks, but How this problem can be solved if SimpleShape class is not available in c#, As Shape class does not have property for location etc.

Comment: You mean if there were a `Shape` class that does not define a location and then there were direct subclasses of `Shape` that all define the `Location` property themselves? Well, my immediate response would be to dump the library you're using and use a properly designed one instead :-). Another possible way would to use `dynamic`, but that takes away type safety at compile time.

Comment: can we dump library..?, please tell me more about it, how can we do this.

Comment: "dump" as in "don't use it", but use something well designed

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the [`Shape`](https://msdn.microsoft.com//library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.shape.aspx) MSDN page, it doesn't seem that Shape has a `Location` property... still you can use `dynamic`:

```
dynamic currentControl2 = currentControl;
int cx = currentControl2.Location.X;
```

**Note that, in this specific case, there is another better possibility, as written by Thorsten Dittmar: using [`SimpleShape`](https://msdn.microsoft.com//library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.simpleshape.aspx).**

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`SimpleShape`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.simpleshape.aspx) class instead. This is the inherited object that has the `Location` property:

```
private void ReArrangeShapeLocationDYNAMIC(SimpleShape currentControl, 
    double scalePrecentageHeight, double scalePrecentageWidth)
{
    int cX = currentControl.Location.X;

}
```